# What constitutes a 'word' in vim?

Tags: vim, lexical-analysis

Let's say we have the following in vim atm:

```
int main () {
    printf("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

In vim, <kbd>w</kbd> moves a word to the right, but what exactly constitutes a 'word'?

---

For example, if I have the cursor on <kbd>p</kbd> of `printf`, pressing <kbd>w</kbd> takes u to `(` and pressing another <kbd>w</kbd> skips the `"` and puts the cursor on the `h` of `hello`.  Why was the `"` skipped ?

Pressing another <kbd>w</kbd> now takes you to the other `"` before the `)` and pressing another `w` takes you to the next line.  Why where the `)` and `;` skipped?

And now the cursor is on the `r` of `return`.  Pressing a <kbd>w</kbd> takes the cursor on `0` and pressing another <kbd>w</kbd> now takes the cursor on the `;`.  So in this case, the `;` was not skipped unlike in the previous line.  Why is this?

---

I hope I made my question clear enough but I'm just trying to understand how this all works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From `:help word`:

> A word consists of a sequence of letters, digits and underscores, or a
>   sequence of other non-blank characters, separated with white space (spaces,
>   tabs, ).  This can be changed with the 'iskeyword' option.  An empty line
>   is also considered to be a word.

If your use capital W instead:

> A WORD consists of a sequence of non-blank characters, separated with white
>   space.  An empty line is also considered to be a WORD.

In your example, `w` treats any sequence of non-keyword letters as a word too.

EDIT: The setting for `virtualedit` will influence this too: You must have it unset, because line-final punctuation is being skipped by `w` (add some whitespace to the end of the line to see the difference). If you set `virtualedit=onemore` the cursor will be able to stop one space beyond the end of the line, and line final punctuation won't ever be skipped.

Answer (score 2):

From within vim, type

```
:help word-motions
```

You will get all the explanation you seek.